# Casting error while trying to read value from data reader

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqldatareader

I am trying to read value from data reader based on column name but i am not getting in what data type(int,double,decimal) i should read that value
because that column will have aggregate operations like `sum,average,count,min,max` etc...

I am getting below error when i am trying to data reader value in double datatype :

```
double unitPrice = dr.GetDouble(0); // index of my column whose value i want to read from data reader
```

> Error : Specified cast is not valid

**Sql Query :**

```
select sum([UnitPrice]) AS unitPrice from [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]
```

Further i have some calculations on this `unitPrice variable` so i am not getting what will be the best way to read this value and in what datatype?

Because of calculations on `unitPrice variable` i am not taking it as string otherwise i have to parse it everywhere in my calculations in double

Comment: `sum` never returns `double`, change your code to `dr.getDecimal(0);` please look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql)

Comment: @styx Ok but as i said sometimes it will be sum,count,avg,max,min so decimal datatype will be suitable for all this aggregate function?

Comment: no `COUNT` returns int, but you check the returning type with `GetFieldType`

Comment: Perhaps a DBNull check might be in order as well

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, using strong typing worked for me:

```
public Double unitPrice = Convert.ToDouble(dr["unitPrice"]);
```

or if you already know the index of the column you want to read:

```
public Double unitPrice = Convert.ToDouble(dr(0));
```